# Having problems with importing file, when trying to build 3d module on web with three.js

Tags: javascript, linux, npm, three.js

```html
import * as THREE from 'three.js'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
);

const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera,renderer,domElement);

const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
scene.add(axesHelper);

camera.position.set(0,2,7.5);
orbit.update();

const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00});
const box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry,boxMaterial);
scene.add(box);

box.rotation.x = 5;
box.rotation.y = 5;

function animate(){
    box.rotation.x += 0.01;
    box.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBqyx.png)
I keep getting error when i want to import three and orbitcontrols.js, but i have already npm install them and they are inside the node_modules file, what should i do in order to make it work?

Comment: if i write it like import * as THREE from "three", it would directly say cannot find declaration file named three, the same case happen to orbitcontrol

Comment: If you're using webpack you can use the code above but if you plug the above code directly into your HTML using <script type="module"> then you need to state actual URLs for the scripts instead. The browser cannot see into your node_modules folder: https://jsfiddle.net/mvL9u6cr/

Comment: "cannot find declaration file" should only show up when you're using TypeScript. Are you trying to use TypeScript with your project?

Comment: I am new to website coding, so i am not sure did i accidentally used tyepscript, but if i am not wrong, i should be only using javascript right here?